# Timer problems with swing GUI components

Tags: java, swing, scala, timer

This snippet of code essentially reveals the back side of the cards when clicked. The `showFace` function sets the icon and text and therefore implying the front of the card. Light gray background is the back. If a non matching card is clicked, I first intend to `showFace` for a brief moment ( 2 seconds) than revert to the "back side of the card." However, upon clicking a non matching card, the icon and text flashes instantaneously and reverts to its gray background.

Tried changing the 2000 milliseconds to something higher but no avail. Any help is appreciated.

```
else if (currentMode == 1){
  //matched cards
  if(checkCards(currentCard, names)){
    showFace();
    currentMode = 0;
    currentCard = "";
    deafTo(this);
  }
  //else non match, still checking mode
  else{
    showFace();
    var timer: Timer = null;
    val action = new ActionListener(){

      override def actionPerformed(event : ActionEvent){
        icon = null;
        text = "";
        background = Color.DARK_GRAY;
        timer.stop();
      }
    };
    timer = new Timer (2000, action);
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    timer.start();
  }
}

def showFace()={
  text = names;
  horizontalTextPosition = Alignment.Center;
  verticalTextPosition = Alignment.Bottom;
  background = Color.WHITE;
  val icons = new ImageIcon(path);
  val newIc = icons.getImage();
  val newIcons = newIc.getScaledInstance(100, 75, 
      java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
  icon = new ImageIcon(newIcons);
  repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you set an initial delay of 2000ms in the constructor

```
timer = new Timer(2000, action)
```

But then you overwrite it to 0ms by:

```
timer.setInitialDelay(0);
```

Remove this line and you should be good.

You can check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#Timer-int-java.awt.event.ActionListener-) Swing Timer API.
And see some examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: Oh my goodness. Thank you! I misread the API and thought `setInitialDelay `caused the timer to go from 0 to 2 seconds!

Comment: You're welcome. Take the time and review both links as they are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

This class does not offer real-time guarantees: it schedules tasks using the Object.wait(long) method.

Java 5.0 introduced the java.util.concurrent package and one of the concurrency utilities therein is the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor which is a thread pool for repeatedly executing tasks at a given rate or delay. It is effectively a more versatile replacement for the Timer/TimerTask combination, as it allows multiple service threads, accepts various time units, and doesn't require subclassing TimerTask (just implement Runnable). Configuring ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with one thread makes it equivalent to Timer.